# using ActiveModelSerializers and having children rendered with specific Seriazlier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, active-model-serializers, ancestry

I have the following relationships (using RoR 3.2.13 and ancestry 2.0.0) and **REALLY** need some help in configuring how the serializer renders with the MenuHeaderSerializer:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_headers
end

class MenuHeader < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry  # the nested relationship
  has_many :items
  belongs_to :menu
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :menu_header
end
```

My serializers are pretty explanatory and look like this:

```
class MenuSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :menu_headers
  has_many :menu_headers
end

class MenuHeaderSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :children # <- this needs to be called and wrapped in a MenuHeaderSerializer; it basically just dumps eveything like to_json
  #has_many :items
end
```

So my call to children should return children using MenuHeaderSerializer. Does that make sense?

I have tried what I think are all of the variations like the following:

```
class MenuHeaderSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :sub # :children #, :sub
  def sub
    MenuHeaderSerializer.new(children)
    #object.children
  end
```

or trying to force children into using the MenuHeaderSerializer but am just at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Perhaps something like:

```
 attributes :id, :name, :children serializer: MenuHeaderSerializer # doesn't work
```

thx

Comment: I'm trying to figure out something similar.
It's been suggested to me to use `embed :ids, include: true` within the ActiveModelSerializer.

But I'm not sure how I'm going to make that work with Ancestry, as that line is meant for `has_many` associations.

Answer (score 1):

not sure about Ancestery but you can do

`has_many :children, each_serializer: MenuHeaderSerializer`

Comment: This solution will produce n+1 query.